Landsat images downloaded with Google Earth Engine contain only clouds
I'm trying to download LANDSAT 9 images using Google Earth Engine. However, despite sorting the images using either CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE or CLOUD_COVER, I only get images of clouds.
I've tried reversing the sort to check if the parameters were sorted from the cloudiest to the clearest, but the result did not change. Our of desperation I downloaded ALL landsat9 images for a given location, and I found that ALL of them contains only clouds.
Why does this happen and how can I get non-cloudy images?
This is my code
import ee
import geemap

# Define collection and bands
COLLECTION = "LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T2_L2"
BANDS = ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2']

# Initialize
service_account = '...@...gserviceaccount.com'
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, '....json')
ee.Initialize(credentials)

# Define point to download. This is a 5km-by-5km area in Pretoria
# This should look something like this:
# https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/landsat-9-image-sansa-ground-station)
point = ee.Geometry.Point((28.009, -25.794))
patch = point.buffer(2500).bounds()

# Filter the ImageColletion
images = ee.ImageCollection(COLLECTION).filterBounds(patch).sort('CLOUD_COVER')

# Download all images
size = images.size().getInfo()
images_list = images.toList(size)
for i in range(size):
    image = ee.Image(images_list.get(i)).select(BANDS).clip(patch)
    geemap.ee_export_image(image, filename=f'landsat_image_{i}.tif', 
                           scale=30, region=patch)

This is the output:

As a comparison, the landsat website shows this image for the same area:

https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/landsat-9-image-sansa-ground-station

It looks like you have specified the coordinates in a wrong way.
Try with point = ee.Geometry.Point((28.009, -25.794))

Not sure to understand. The image from the USGS webpage is from Pretoria, South Africa, which is at 25°43′S 28°17′E, i.e. longitude 28°17′E and latitude 25°43′S, i.e. x=28.___ and y=-25.___, i.e. ee.Geometry.Point((28.009, -25.794)), not ee.Geometry.Point((-25.794, 28.009)). What's wrong?

@AndreaGiudiceandrea I'm extremely sorry (I usually double check these things). You were right: this was a copypasting error here in StackExchange. The images I posted are indeed obtained using point = ee.Geometry.Point((28.009, -25.794)).
I rerun the code for safety and I confirm these are the images I obtain.
I fixed the code above. My apologies for the reply above.

You are using Tier 2 data, which are by definition a subset that contains less quality images. See here

Landsat scenes not meeting Tier 1 criteria during processing are
assigned to Tier 2. Tier 2 scenes adhere to the same radiometric
standard as Tier 1 scenes, but do not meet the Tier 1 geometry
specification due to less accurate orbital information (specific to
older Landsat sensors), significant cloud cover, insufficient ground
control, or other factors.

To use the highest available data quality use Tier 1 data
# Define collection and bands
COLLECTION = "LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2"

